# How Can I Implement MOEA/D Algorithm in Java From Pseudocode?

Tags: optimization, java, metaheuristics

I want to implement MOEA/D algorithm for a spesific population but I could not figure out how to write the java code from the pseudocode.

My population size is 50 and the chromosomes shape is like this: [1,0,0,1,0,0,], so the people are made of binary genes. Is there any simple implementation of that algorithm without using any framework? The steps are not clear for me. I have also tried to convert an matlab code but did not work. Where can I find an basic implementation of that algorithm?

My Problem:

```
Pop[i] = [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,.....,1,0]
ObjectiveFunction1(Pop[i]): return count of 1 // the aim is to minimize
ObjectiveFunction2(Pop[i]): return x // x is the result of some calculations with using 1s, the aim is to maximize
```

Comment: If you want to understand the pseudocode, please explain your problem in more detail. Also you could explain what is the issue with converting from the matlab code. There might not be a code already done for Java in particular.

Comment: @Erwan there are many array-vector operations in the pseudocode, these are hard to convert to java. I looked an matlab code but could not convert to java, because there were many expressions that I could not figured out.

Comment: You could look at python implementation if it helps: https://github.com/anyoptimization/pymoo. Otherwise your question is not specific enough: if the difficulty is about these 2 functions, the first one seems trivial (just counting the 1s in the input vector), the 2nd one is not formal enough ("some calculation" ?).